# Access DOM from a different html file with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Is there a way to get the DOM elements from another HTML file rather than the elements from the HTML file that calls the JS file?

My idea is to make html templates, and render them in a main html file, depending on certain conditions imposed by the JS file.

Something like

```js
var initScreen = new document(URL);
document.getElementById("body") = initScreen.getElementById("body");
```

supposing that this is the correct way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep. You can fetch a remote (or local) file and then use [`createHTMLDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument):

```js
document.querySelector(".the_replacer").addEventListener("click", () => {
    fetch("https://cdn.rawgit.com/ryanpcmcquen/c22afdb4e6987463efebcd495a105d6d/raw/476e97277632e89a03001cb048c6cacdb727028e/other_file.html")
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((text) => {
            const otherDoc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("Foo").documentElement;
            otherDoc.innerHTML = text;
            document.querySelector(".element_on_main_page").textContent = otherDoc.querySelector(".awesome_external_element").textContent;
        });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="element_on_main_page">Replace me, please.</div>
    <button class="the_replacer">Replace them.</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

https://repl.it/@ryanpcmcquen/TurboTremendousProgramminglanguages

Here's the remote file's contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="awesome_external_element">Foobar.</div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument#Browser_compatibility) is not too bad. On the other hand [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) is pretty modern, so if you are going for legacy support you should use [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: `<link>` tags do not use or need a closing slash.

Comment: @Rob, I bet they would fix it if you contacted them. Although closing slashes are coming back with a vengeance thanks to React.

Comment: The React people need to learn how to read the HTML spec, too.

Comment: What if I load an iframe, with the url, and in the first render take them out of the html, and via JS, extract what i need from them, and keep them as variables in the JS code?

Comment: @ekiim, there is no need to involve an iframe. As you can see in my answer, everything can be stored in JS variables _without_ the use of an iframe. An iframe just adds needless complexity.

Comment: @ekiim, do you have any questions?

Comment: No, it actually worked, now I just need to work on the design of my "areas" according to the size of the defined area in the main HTML. TY

Comment: @ekiim, thank you. If it works for you please accept the answer.