# How can I include HTML page with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to add any HTML document or snippets  to another HTML page with JavaScript, like PHP ("include.php"), or masterpage to ASP.

- Do I need a server?
- Is it possible with JavaScript without local server?

Comment: You can checkout this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48759511/13638824

Comment: Generally, it's best to have all of that HTML baked into the page ahead of time.  It isn't necessary to do it on-request (as you normally do with PHP).  You can use something like a Node.js script to compile your HTML ahead of time.

Comment: you can do that using iFrame or Object